# Trying to generate a return url when mvc app is not the root site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller that generates a return url and then supplys it to the view for a javascript redirect. The problem is on my live site, the application is not the root site so I get some strange results from UriBuilder or when using Response.UrlRefferrer. Here's what I've finally got to sort of work

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [DisableCache]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = null;

        if (Request.UrlReferrer != null)
        {
           uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(Request.UrlReferrer);
        }
        else
        {
            uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("prodsite");
        }
        //uriBuilder.Path += path;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
        return View();
    }
```

This solution works when the user uses a direct link to the controller, but if, say the user bookmarks this page and returns to it through their browser's link, the url becomes the root of the site. I really wish I had a more MVCish way to handle the urls, but nothing so far has worked. Any suggestions? Also, I'm looking for a way to make this work on both live and test sites if that's at all possible so I don't have to go in and manually change code around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using Url.Action?  In our javascript we use

```
window.location = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
```

and the links work local and on production.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks man. I had to change a few things to provide the action and the controller. I also had to provide the scheme to the parameters to get the absolute url exa: window.location = '@Url.Action(ViewBag.returnAction, ViewBag.returnController, null, Request.Url.Scheme)';